# Android: Which Message priority is highest in Logcat Monitoring?

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

When I run my First Android Application I got pop-up message showing

[image]

So which message is having least priority? Till now I just select the default "error" and press OK. Another thing is how can I change this option afterwards?

Comment: to see everything, you should choose "verbose"

Comment: @Adem it means that the list is sorted from least priority to the highest one. Assert will be the highest priority messages than.

Comment: Verbose shows you all the log (errors, info,...), so maybe it's better if you choose it. Otherwise, it's not a problem, you can change this option later.

Comment: @DonChakkappan nice joke (:  Google develop ADT for Eclipse.

Comment: If you are using LogRabbit on Mac you just select the log level you want in the left column. I usually keep logging turned off in Eclipse because it is so bad. If you are using Eclipse you can use the dropdown on the right of the log window to change the filtered log level.